# How to find rows with overlapping date ranges?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains data like below (tiny subset of data):

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a way where I can create a new dataframe that contains all rows that have the same values for : `carrier`, `flightnumber`, `departureAirport` and `arrivalAirport` but also have date ranges that overlap.

By overlap I mean the `effectiveDate` for one row falls between the `effectiveDate` and `discontinuedDate` for another record that has the same values for the other columns I mentioned.

So in my above example, the first two rows would be considered an example of this (and should both be included in the new dataframe), but the third row is not.

I'm assuming I want to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), but I'm not entirely clear on what aggregation function I would apply.  Below is what I have so far:

```
df.groupby(['carrier','flightnumber','departureAirport','arrivalAirport'])['effectiveDate', 'discontinuedDate'].min()
```

but obviously I need to apply a function that determines overlap instead of `min()`.  How would I go about identifying overlap instead of returning the minimum values for this group?

UPDATE:

```
carrier flightnumber  departureAirport  arrivalAirport  effectiveDate discontinuedDate
4U      9748          DUS               GVA             2017-05-09    2017-07-12
4U      9748          DUS               GVA             2017-05-14    2017-07-16
4U      9748          DUS               GVA             2017-07-18    2017-08-27
AG      1234          SFO               DFW             2017-03-09    2017-05-12
AG      1234          SFO               DFW             2017-03-14    2017-05-16
```

UPDATE 2:

As far as output goes I'd like to have any rows that overlap and have the same values for `carrier`, `flightnumber`, `departureAirport` and `arrivalAirport` returned in a new dataframe.  There does not need to be any additional data included for these rows.  So for the above example data, a dataframe like the one below would be my desired output:

```
carrier flightnumber  departureAirport  arrivalAirport  effectiveDate discontinuedDate
4U      9748          DUS               GVA             2017-05-09    2017-07-12
4U      9748          DUS               GVA             2017-05-14    2017-07-16
AG      1234          SFO               DFW             2017-03-09    2017-05-12
AG      1234          SFO               DFW             2017-03-14    2017-05-16
```

Notice that only one record has been excluded (the third for `9748`) - this is because it's date range does not overlap with other records for the same flight.

Comment: What do you want to do when more than one subgroup overlaps, or two date ranges overlap with a third but not each other? Or does something prevent these scenarios?

Comment: If more than one row overlaps i'd like to return all of them.  If any row overlaps with any other row i'd like to return it regardless of it's relationship with any other rows.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @piRSquared - sure.  I went ahead and added a second update regarding my desired output.  If you are still around feel free to take a look and let me know if it helps clarify.  Cheers

Comment: @AbeMiessler perfect.  In my opinion, that is now unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**High Level Concept**

- Sort by all dates and then by prioritizing `effectiveDate` if there is exact overlap.
- Cumulatively sum to alternating ones and negative ones that were initialized prior to sorting.  The point is that an overlap happens when the cumulative sum is above `1`.  A contiguous group ends when the sum drops to `0`.
- Unsort the sorting and identify where zeros happen...  these are the end of overlapping groups.
- Split the dataframe index on these break points and only take the splits where the size of the split is greater than `1`.
- Concatenate the passing splits and use `loc` to get the sliced dataframe.

---

```
def overlaping_groups(df):
    n = len(df)
    cols = ['effectiveDate', 'discontinuedDate']
    v = np.column_stack([df[c].values for c in cols]).ravel()
    i = np.tile([1, -1], n)
    a = np.lexsort([-i, v])
    u = np.empty_like(a)
    u[a] = np.arange(a.size)
    e = np.flatnonzero(i[a].cumsum()[u][1::2] == 0)
    d = np.diff(np.append(-1, e))
    s = np.split(df.index.values, e[:-1] + 1)

    return df.loc[np.concatenate([g for j, g in enumerate(s) if d[j] > 1])]

gcols = ['carrier', 'flightnumber', 'departureAirport', 'arrivalAirport']
df.groupby(gcols, group_keys=False).apply(overlaping_groups)

  carrier  flightnumber departureAirport arrivalAirport effectiveDate discontinuedDate
0      4U          9748              DUS            GVA    2017-05-09       2017-07-12
1      4U          9748              DUS            GVA    2017-05-14       2017-07-16
3      AG          1234              SFO            DFW    2017-03-09       2017-05-12
4      AG          1234              SFO            DFW    2017-03-14       2017-05-16
```

Comment: I have tried to recreate this and it throws the error - ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate .  (python: 3.7.1, pandas: 0.24.2) @piRSquared